# State Machines - Can you model alternatives flows?

Tags: uml, state-machine, visual-paradigm

I am trying to implement a state machine, however I am very confused about it at the moment.

Can you have states that model alternative flows, such as Vehicles not existing - if a penalty fine is to be issued, or a Reg no being invalid?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your problem - state machine has no easily visible fork element in VP UMP . But it needn't. Every state block works as multi-fork. All arrows from a state to other ones are cases, "what changes if..." The text of condition is on the arrow. An arrow can have more, than one condition.
So, the answer is 
YES!

And really you can use forks, too. They are hidden under "initial pseudo state". But use them only if there is one event coming from a state and it is forking without the relation to a state. Or if it starts some flow.

Answer (score 2):

I can't commment yet, therefore feedback to your question is not possible for me in another way than answer. My answer'd depend on your problem

1. If you're thinking in flows maybe you should use an activity diagram instead of a state machine, there's a difference between the functional und the behavioural view.
2. Rethink the states you use
3. Use a hierarchical state machine (e.g. have a look in http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Introduction-Hierarchical-State-Machines)

Answer (score 0):

There are alternative flows and paralel execution possible in state machines of course. Use Shoice pseudstate to define alternative transitions. Condition to decide outging transition is defined as a guard of transition. States must reside in the same region. For concurrent states activation, use Fork pseudostate. Transitions outgoing from fork pseudostate must be directed to the states, all in differen regions.